# Is this iptables firewall bash script good?

Tags: bash, linux, networking, shell

I'm learning to use iptables to implement it in my company software. The goal is either to prevent the major attacks and to have good speed transferring files (ssh and ftp). Can you help me to improve it or to discover errors? 

generic ip = 192.168.1.120
ethernet card = eth0

```or-tag-here
#!/bin/sh
#######################################
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: firewall
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog $remote_fs
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog $remote_fs
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: Personal Firewall - Preventing attacks/open common ports
### END INIT INFO 

### Module loading ###
/sbin/depmod -a
### Required modules ###
/sbin/modprobe ip_tables
/sbin/modprobe iptable_filter
/sbin/modprobe ipt_REJECT
/sbin/modprobe iptable_nat
/sbin/modprobe ipt_LOG
/sbin/modprobe ipt_limit
### Non-Required modules ###
#/sbin/modprobe ipt_owner
#/sbin/modprobe iptable_mangle
#/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack
#/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
#/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_irc
#/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp
#/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_irc
#/sbin/modprobe ipt_MASQUERADE

# To start the firewall
start()
{
    ### Allow Forward ip ###
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    ### Flush any Existing iptable Rules and start afresh ###
    iptables -F INPUT
    iptables -F OUTPUT
    iptables -F FORWARD
    iptables -F POSTROUTING -t nat
    iptables -F PREROUTING -t nat

    ### Setting up Port Services ###
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT    //incoming mail
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT    //dns - udp for large queries
    iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT    //dns - udp for small queries
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT    //apache
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT    //apache ssl
    iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT   //snmpd
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 953 -j ACCEPT    //dns internal
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1080 -j ACCEPT    //dante socks server
    iptables -A INPUT -p all --dport 3020 -j ACCEPT  //cifs-smb
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT  //squid
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4949 -j ACCEPT   //munin stats

    ### Setting up Local Ports ###
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p udp --dport 9 -j ACCEPT    //WOL (wake on lan)
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT     //ftp
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT       //sshd
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT     //samba
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT    //imaps
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT     //mysql
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT    //apache on phi
    iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT   //tomcat
    iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT       //to speed up mail via courier. Identified via logging
    iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT      //squirrelmail

    ### Preventing Attacks ###
    iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT      //Allow ICMP Ping packets.
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK -j ACCEPT      //Accept traffic with the ACK flag set
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP             //Deny all null packets
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP             //Deny all recon packets
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN -j DROP            //nmap FIN stealth scan
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP       //SYN + FIN
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP      //SYN + RST
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP     //FIN + RST
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP    //FIN + URG + PSH
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL URG,ACK,PSH,RST,SYN,FIN -j DROP       //XMAS
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP       //FIN without ACK
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j DROP      //PSH without ACK
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP     //URG without ACK
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP        //Deny SYN flood attack
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT     //Accept traffic with ESTABLISHED flag set (limit - DDoS prevent)
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT        //Accept traffic with RELATED flag set (limit - DDoS prevent)
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP       //Deny traffic with the INVALID flag set
    #################################

    ### PERSONALIZED RULES 80 PORT ###
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT       //Protection DDoS attacks
    ### PERSONALIZED RULES 22 PORT ###
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m recent --rcheck --seconds 30 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset      //Protection bruteforce SSH
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m recent --rcheck --seconds 30 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH brute force "
    iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

    ########### CLOSE ALL ############
    iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT         //Close up firewall. All else blocked.

    ######### PORT FORWARDING #######
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.120 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to 1.2.3.4:80
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.2.3.4     //for static ip
    #iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -j MASQUERADE       //for dynamic ip
    #################################

    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Firewall Loaded"
    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Netstat output:"
    echo ""
    netstat -tuanp
    echo "Verify enabled rules with:"
    echo "filter) iptables -L -nvx"
    echo "nat) iptables -t nat -L -nvx"
    echo "script) firewall.sh status"
    EXT=0
}

### To stop the firewall ###
stop()
{
    ### Deny Forward ip ###
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Firewall Stopped"
    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    EXT=0
}

### To clear rules ###
clear()
{
    iptables -F INPUT
    iptables -F OUTPUT
    iptables -F FORWARD
    iptables -F POSTROUTING -t nat
    iptables -F PREROUTING -t nat
    EXT=0
}

case $1 in
    start)
          clear
          start
    ;;
    stop)
         clear
         stop
    ;;
    restart)
            clear
            sleep 2
            start
    ;;
    status)
           echo "--------------------------------------------------"
           echo "--------------------------------------------------"
           echo "Status Firewall"
           echo "--------------------------------------------------"
           #iptables -L -n
           echo "--------------------------------------------------"
           echo "FILTER"
           echo "--------------------------------------------------"
           iptables -L -nvx
           echo "--------------------------------------------------"
           echo "NAT"
           echo "--------------------------------------------------"           
           iptables -t nat -L -nvx
           EXT=0
    ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: firewall.sh {start|stop|restart|status}"
      EXT=1
    ;;
esac
exit $EXT
```

Comment: Is your question about the structure of the code or about the effectiveness of the iptables rules?  I suspect you want to know if the collection of firewall rules is effective in meeting your two goals.  You will want to know if there are gaps in your firewall rule coverage, but I doubt you care if it is clunky shell script as long as it does the basic job.  In which case. ServerFault or Unix & Linux would be the right place for this.

Comment: I post it yet in server fault, but they send me here. My question isn't concerned to the structure of the code, but if it can deny/prevent attacks like ddos,nmap or something else and, generally, if it's a good firewall script. The "iptables argument" is too wide to study in a "company work"... I haven't enough time.. I tried to balance diligence with productivity. Can you explain me if what i'm thinking about the code is right or do it need to be improved?

Comment: You don't introduce comments using `//` in Bash. What's going on in your code?

Comment: ServerFault shouldn't have sent you here.  It really isn't this site's role to tell you if you have the right iptables rules and if they are good iptables rules.

Comment: so... nobody wants me :D

Comment: I just checked ServerFault.  Your question was closed for lack of sufficient information.  *One* user then told you to come here.

Answer (score 3):

As [@itsbruce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28541/itsbruce) pointed out,
to get criticism on the robustness of the firewall rules,
it will be better to ask on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).
I can review mostly in terms of general Bash scripting,
and only a little bit in terms of basic security concerns.

---

This seems to be a security concern to me:

> ```
> ### To stop the firewall ###
> stop()
> {
>     ### Deny Forward ip ###
>     echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
>     echo "--------------------------------------------------"
>     echo "Firewall Stopped"
>     echo "--------------------------------------------------"
>     EXT=0
> }
> ```

I could be wrong, but I don't think this stops the firewall.
This only stops the port forwarding rules for NAT,
everything else will continue to work normally.

Also, flushing all the tables doesn't sound like a good default set of rules.
I'd keep at least this default rule always:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

While setting up the rules,
I will still keep this in first position,
and when everything is ready,
delete it.
But I'm not sure that's the best way either,
and on Unix & Linux they can probably suggest something better.

---

In terms of Bash scripting, it's mostly fine, with some repetitions standing out:

- Put the IP address `192.168.1.120` in a variable, defined at the top where easy to see
- Same for the network interface `eth0`
- I'd create a function to print the separator line `echo "--------------------------------------------------"`, to make it easier to type, and easier to change if needed later

Finally, it maybe a matter of taste, but there's no need to quote in `echo "Status Firewall"`, `echo "FILTER"`, `echo "NAT"`, so I'd just drop those quotes.

Comment: Thank you for asking me! I'll try to be clear to you: -"stop case" has clear and stop functions, the real "stop case" is clear... I use it becouse in iptables command is more logical call clear and not stop (you clear all charged rules); -reject i uderstood it's vulnerable to ddos attacks, is it possible? for the variables i replace them when i'll complete the script. Ok for the status advice! Thanks

Comment: A `stop` function that doesn't stop the firewall should be called something else. For example `stop_forwarding`.